# illegal offset type in php on vscode no error, but on page says that error

Tags: php

hello i'm running into a problem, it says on the browser illegal offset type,
im declaring an array this way:

```
 $matriculas = [
        1 => ["99-99-99", "D"],
        2 => ["88-88-88", "D"],
    ];
```

and the error is in this line :

```
 $series[$option] = [$option['matricula'],$option['type']];
```

the function looks like this:

```
<?php 
    $query ="SELECT * FROM matriculas";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    if($result->num_rows> 0){
      $options= mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
    $series = array();
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $series[$option] = [$option['matricula'],$option['type']];
    }
?>
<select name="id">
   <option>Select matricula</option>
<?php 
  foreach ($series as $ID => $values) {
?>
    <option name=<?php $ID ?> > <?php echo $values[0]; ?></option>
<?php 
}
>
</select>
```

how can i make it right? thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How is that `$matriculas` array related to the code? It is unused

Comment: `$series[$option]` As `$option` is also an array . I doubt you actually want to do that.

Comment: i want to fetch a table into a form and display only the name on a select, then when user selects the name it posts the name (matricula) and the type

Comment: As we have NO IDEA what the column names are and therefore the content of the SQL Query its difficult to give any more help but maybe `$series[] = [$option['matricula'],$option['type']];` is what you intended OR Maybe `$series[$option['something']] = [$option['matricula'],$option['type']];`

Comment: the table name is : matriculas, with the columns : id,matricula,type, now it alredy displays the page but its not posting matricula alongside with type, each matricula has a type, wich i want to post automatticly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost right.

Based on the subsequent `foreach ($series as $ID => $values)`, I think you want this instead:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $series[$option['id']] = [$option['matricula'], $option['type']];
}
```

But unless you're going to use the `$option['type']` value for something else later, it could be simplified to

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $series[$option['id']] = $option['matricula'];
}
```

Comment: i think this is the correct option, in my insert page how should i post the matricula and type making them go to separate columns in the same table , ? i currently tried posting "matricula" and posting "type" but its going null on form submission

Comment: Currently, these values do not appear in a Table in your code, do you mean how to place the values into the `<OPTION>` tag?

Comment: just the matricula, making the type hidden, correlated with each matricula, and post it after submitting the form with a matricula selected( select has alredy got matricula ) i want is to post also the type with selecting a matricula

Answer (score 0):

Option in your case is an array and you cannot make an array the key of the index. So instead of `$series[$option]` you should do `$series[$option['matricula']]` or `$series[$option['type']]` as its a single value.

Answer (score 0):

instead of that why you don't modify this to fit?
so then where you have `foreach ($series as $ID => $values) {`  to replace that with `echo $sum;`
so try to modify the piece in this way (you may modify it in case isn't work but the idea is to not fill the memory with a new array but what you read already to sum it and output text as template insertion)

```
$sum='';
$series = array();
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        //nope! $series[$option] = [$option['matricula'],$option['type']];
$sum.=<<<opt

 <option name="{$option['matricula']}">{$option['type']}</option>
opt;
 }
```